# API Management advanced policies - Limit concurrency to 1

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, policies

I have an API in Azure API Management with multiple operations. One specific of those operations should have an limit execution concurrency of 1. I tried to limit the parallel execution with the following backend policie, like in the Microsoft Docs explained.

```
<backend>
    <limit-concurrency key="general" max-count="1">
        <forward-request timeout="120" />
    </limit-concurrency>
</backend>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#LimitConcurrency

Unfortunatly the behaviour of this limit is that I can execute the operation twice at the same time. The third parallel execution results in an 429 status code.

Someone has any glue why a max-count of 1 results in a max-count of 2?

Comment: you must implement it using DB or a Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use concurrency control we can guarantee that the backend system don’t have more than 2 concurrent calls and all calls after are queued up to a maximum limit, and processed right away as one of the 2 concurrent calls are finished. Making sure to not waste resources in retry and idle time. Using the Concurrency control is simple here is the policy:

```
<limit-concurrency key="general" max-count="1" timeout="120" max-queue-length="100">
    <forward-request timeout="120" />
</limit-concurrency>
```

For more details, you can refer to this [article](https://mlogdberg.com/apimanagement/concurrency-control).

Comment: Yes as I wrote I know this possibility. But unfortunately my backend service can't process 2 concurrent calls. So I need to make sure, it only receives only 1 concurrent call. 
And if I set max-count to 1 it acts like it is set to 2...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this policy and it looks like the timeout and max-queue-length options are not supported. They are also not documented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/limit-concurrency-policy

My code:

```
<backend>
    <limit-concurrency key="@(context.Subscription.Name)" max-count="1" timeout="120" max-queue-length="100">
        <forward-request timeout="120"/>
    </limit-concurrency>
</backend>
```

I get the error: "Error in element 'limit-concurrency' on line 174, column 4: The 'timeout' attribute is not declared."